# Drupal Form foreach loop

Tags: drupal, forms, drupal-6

I wonder if anyone can help me out with this..
I have a foreach loop in a form in drupal which iterates through options for some JQuery sliders. 
This works fine.
However I wanted to add a markup field within the loop, so that I could have a header div above wach slider. Instead of looping through each one, it displayed all 4 headers in one go, then all 4 sliders? Is this the correct behaviour? Please see below.

```
foreach ($categories as $key => $title) {

$form['sliderHead'][$key] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#value' => "<div id='sliderHeaders'>Header Text</div>"
);

$form['vote'][$key] = array(
  '#type' => 'slider',
  '#title' => $title,
  '#name' => $key, // TODO: define it with the $key variable.
  '#options' => $options,
);
```

}

Thanks a lot,
Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slider is not a valid type.  Are you using another module to provide that type?

If so:

```
foreach ($categories as $key => $title) {
  $form['vote'][$key] = array(
    '#type' => 'slider',
    '#title' => $title,
    '#prefix' => t("<div id='sliderHeaders'>Header Text</div>"),
    '#name' => $key, // TODO: define it with the $key variable.
    '#options' => $options,
  );
}
```

Use the `#prefix` form attribute.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks a lot that has sorted my problem. Yes, the type is provided elsewhere. Just out of interest though, any idea why it does the loop out of order, is that normal?

Comment: Yes, that is normal - it's defined in the way that Drupal creates it's forms (from formapis)

Answer (score 1):

Because Drupal renders in order of array depth unless you specify a `#weight` for everything, then it will order by weight.

So if you don't want to use weights you could have done it like this although the suggestion above using `#prefix` is better for your case:

```
foreach ($categories as $key => $title) {

  $form['slider']['head'][$key] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#value' => "<div id='sliderHeaders'>Header Text</div>"
  );

  $form['slider']['vote'][$key] = array(
    '#type' => 'slider',
    '#title' => $title,
    '#name' => $key, // TODO: define it with the $key variable.
    '#options' => $options,
  );

}
```

Comment: Thats interesting, I can sleep at nights now! :)